# Setting height for table in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I've created a table with 2 columns. In the second cell of the first row I want to insert another table that have only one cell. The problem is that I can't set the height of the second table. It stretches more than the content height. Its height is equal with the cell height where it was added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height of the table cannot be set, the height of the table is determined by the height of its cells (you can set the height-property of a cell). You could add an empty cell to the second table if you want to stretch this table.

Answer (score 10):

Table's height depends on its parent container. So you should set height of the parent cell. You can do this in two ways:

```
cell.MinimumHeight = 50f;
```

or

```
 cell.FixedHeight = 70f;
```